# Azure boards, when user stories exported CSV file created with html tags

Tags: azure-devops, export-to-csv, user-stories, azure-boards

How to export the user stories without html tags? we need to release this data to business users, how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is by-designed:

> This is the expected behavior. If the html tags were removed, then
>   **re-importing the exported data** would cause formatting to be removed,
>   thus the formatting elements are kept in the exported output.

Take a look at below similar questions:

- [CSV export has unnecessary pieces of information](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/564465/csv-export-has-unnecessary-pieces-of-information.html)
- [export in csv containing unnecessary html code](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/842879/export-in-csv-containing-unnecessary-html-code.html)

You may have to manually  strip the HTML from it. Sorry for any inconvenience.